# Sharepoint 2013 designer workflow publish error

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am trying to publish SharePoint 2013 designer workflow to SharePoint online site.
This is a existing workflow and couple of changes made and there are no any errors in the workflow.
But When I am trying to publish it, it is throwing me the error -

Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityValidationException: Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors: Visual Basic expression is disallowed: '[Nothing]'.
Visual Basic expression is disallowed: '[Nothing]'.
HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: ID here. NodeId: . Scope: . Client ActivityId : ID here. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
at Microsoft.Workflow.

Kindly suggest what needs to be done.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Starting August 1st, 2020, SharePoint 2010 workflows will be turned off for newly created tenants.

Starting November 1st, 2020, Microsoft will begin to remove the ability to run or create SharePoint 2010 workflows from existing tenants.

It is recommended to create Power Automate flow.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f

Comment: Thanks for the Information. I have got this info though. But the issue mentioned here is with 2013 workflow